# contactenating two arrays in c using pointers and function

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

```
int* concat_tab(int n1,int t1[],int n2, int t2[]){
    int *t3;
    t3 = (int*) malloc((n1+n2)*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
            *(t3+i)=*(t1+i);}
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++){
            *(t3+n1+j)=*(t2+j);}
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n1+n2; i++){
        printf("%d\t",*(t3+i));}
}
```

I'm trying to use this function two arrays but I get a segmentation fault. Any Help!

Comment: Your function is declared as returning an `int*` but it doesn't. Add `return t3;` at the end.

Comment: Show us also the main.

Comment: OT: `(int*) malloc` -> `malloc`, the cast is unnecessary.

Comment: The function correctly runs, but doesn't return t3 as Adrian said above! (after the use of the returned value of t3, in example `xx=concat_tab`in the main,  remember to free it ( `free(xx);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't have a `return t3;` statement.